# add new value in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

It's my adapter

```
String[] company = new String[company_name.size()];
company = company_name.toArray(company);

String[] position = new String[business_name.size()];
position = business_name.toArray(position);
String[] state = new String[state_name.size()];
state = state_name.toArray(state);
String[] city = new String[city_name.size()];
city = city_name.toArray(city);

String[] url_str = new String[url_list.size()];
url_str = url_list.toArray(url_str);

String[] desc_str = new String[desc_list.size()];
desc_str = desc_list.toArray(desc_str);

datadap= new Data(this,company,position,city,state,pass_value,desc_str);
listView.setAdapter(datadap);
```

Now I want to create more string objects
like this

```
String[] company = new String[company_name.size()];
company = company_name.toArray(company);

String[] position = new String[business_name.size()];
position = business_name.toArray(position);
String[] state = new String[state_name.size()];
state = state_name.toArray(state);
String[] city = new String[city_name.size()];
city = city_name.toArray(city);

String[] url_str = new String[url_list.size()];
url_str = url_list.toArray(url_str);

String[] desc_str = new String[desc_list.size()];
desc_str = desc_list.toArray(desc_str);
```

And please suggest me how I want to add this value in adapter

Comment: Before proceeding, I suggest u to hv a look at types of adapters and then choose appropriate one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a class that extends ArrayAdapter. This class overrides the getView
method where you specify what you want to display and where.
The constructor of this arrayadapter asks for an array list of the type (class) you want.
When you change this arraylist, call notifydatasetchanged on the array adapter
and you're ready to go :)

More info: [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

first you must to rename values:

```
String[] company1 = new String[company_name.size()];
company = company_name.toArray(company1);

String[] position1 = new String[business_name.size()];
position = business_name.toArray(position1);
String[] state1 = new String[state_name.size()];
state = state_name.toArray(state1);
String[] city1 = new String[city_name.size()];
city = city_name.toArray(city1);

String[] url_str1 = new String[url_list.size()];
url_str = url_list.toArray(url_str1);

String[] desc_str1 = new String[desc_list.size()];
desc_str = desc_list.toArray(desc_str1);
```

then you can add the same thing you added before:

```
datadap= new Data(this,company1,position1,city1,state1,pass_value1,desc_str1);
listView.setAdapter(datadap);
```